# Can't get back to index only get this message "pymysql.err.ERROR :Already closed"

Tags: mysql, flask

I trying to get back to last page after update data and then i get

> pymysql.err.ERROR :Already closed

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for

import pymysql

app = Flask(__name__)

conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="studentdb")

@app.route("/")

def showdata():

    with conn:

        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM student')

        row = cur.fetchall()

    return render_template('index.html', datas = row)
```